# Etymology of 'cartesian'

Tags: etymology

Because of the fact that Rene Descartes developed the Cartesian coordinate system, I would think that the word Cartesian would be named after him (Des-*cartes*). However, I can't shake the feeling that it should be named after the Latin `carta`, meaning map: after all, the Cartesian system is a mapping system.

Or maybe Descartes isn't the inventor's real name, and he changed his name to that after discovering the system?

Could someone help me out here?

Comment: For future reference, try http://etymonline.com/ for etymology.

Comment: I was about to ask the question here then I typed Cartesian into the title box and this popped up. Thanks!

Comment: Tempting as it may be, the conjecture that the name "Descartes" refers to his geometrical invention and method, is provably wrong.

The name Descartes is known to have first been used by the philosopher in his Law Thesis from 1616, long before he explicitly developed the idea of mapping thoughts, let alone the idea of a geometrical coordinate system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=cartesian&searchmode=none), *Cartesian* is the:

> …Latinized form of the name of French philosopher and mathematician René Descartes (1596-1650).

So yes, it is named after him.

Comment: Exactly. The reason is that *des-* merely means "of", so it is like calling a symphony *Beethovian* rather than *Vanbeethovian* after Ludwig van Beethoven, except that the preposition happens to be written attached to *Cartes* nowadays so it is harder to recognize. There was considerably more freedom in spelling in those days, so both *des Cartes* and *Descartes* were probably acceptable. Note that *des* literally means "of the" (*van* means "of").

Answer (score 6):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cartesian) shows that *Cartesian* is derived from the Latinised form of "Descartes", *Cartesius*.

Answer (score 6):

If you are asking why it isn't called the "Descartesian" system. Descartes would originally have meant "of Cartes" and presumably some distant ancestor came from a village called Cartes

So when his name was latinised they dropped the 'of' part and based it on the main part - *cartes*

Answer (score 0):

It is after Descartes and not a map or "carte". [Cartesian geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) is actually the main etymological driver here. As Descarte, amongst other things, actually came up with placing 2 numberlines perpendicularly in order to create the X-Y co-ordinate system we all know and love. In fact it wouldn't surprise me if the term *carte* (for map) is itself derived from Descartes.

Comment: The term *carte* for map predates Descartes.  According to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/carte): "before 1150; Middle English, Old English:  writing paper, document, letter < Latin *charta*  < Greek *chártēs*  sheet of papyrus".  The similarity appears to be entirely coincidental.

Comment: Per the Magna Carta, *carta* is Latin.  I don't know where @KeithThompson got his phantom *h* from.

Comment: @tchrist: As I said, I got it from [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/carte), which could well be incorrect; [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chart) shows the Latin as *carta*.

Answer (score -1):

Let's not forget Jacques Cartier b.1491
[Jacques Cartier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Cartier)

And Wiktionary has *carte* derived from the Greek
[carte](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carte#Etymology)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).